# Node js routing / api request with params - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, get-request

I am making a simple route to request data from an api and test it with postman. However, it im not getting data but error instead and I dont know what I am doing wrong. Anyone knows? Thanks!!

The route with hardcoded param would work:

```
https://api.example.com/list/lists/cities/NYC/airports
```

now my route with params:

```
router.get('/testing', function(req,res) {
    example.get('/list/lists/cities/:city/airports', options, function(err, data){
        if (err){                
            res.status(200).send(err);
        }
        else{
            res.status(200).send(data);
        }
    });
});
```

On postman I simply make a request to: localhost:1337/testing and add to params city and NYC (as an example).

Comment: What is "example"? is that an http client?

Answer (score 0):

You have a "city" placeholder in

```
example.get('/list/lists/cities/:city/airports', options, function(err, data){
```

which you aren't passing in.

Try this:

```
router.get('/testing/:city', function(req,res) {
example.get('/list/lists/cities/' + req.params.city + '/airports', options, function(err, data){
    if (err){                
        res.status(200).send(err);
    }
    else{
        res.status(200).send(data);
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Unfortunately its not working either. In postman I make the get request to http://localhost:1337/testing/:city and type in the param and still get a 404